# Is it possible to not allow NULL in a parameter query in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I basically want to make sure my users are typing something into the parameter when prompted.  Not just hitting "enter" and leaving the parameter null.

I didn't know if there was an easy way to do this in Access, or would I need to use a form to run code?

Comment: Is the parameterized query for an insert/update operation? If so, consider changing the underlying table columns to Not Null. This should throw an error if the user attempts to pass in a Null.

Comment: It is nearly always best to use a form to get parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do at the query level is to submit a default value when user has left the parameter null.

Something like this:

```
WHERE table.column=
  IIf([enter param] is null,"Default Value",[enter param]);
```

Of course you'd need a default/dummy record to return in order to indicate that they left the field blank. Not a best practice.

Comment: Why check the `LEN` of the parameter? `Iif([enter param] IS NULL, "Default Value", [enter param])`

Comment: @Zev You're right. I'll edit the post. I must have had an error in the test I ran.